# Show Authors and excerpt of their last post in a list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've search everywhere but haven't found what I'mlooking for even though I'm convinced there must be a solution floating around since it's obviously such a common request:

I want to display a list of authors with a short excerpt of their latest post.

I have a list of Authors with their images (using the 'Author Avatars List') but what I'm missing is the display of an excerpt of their latest posts next/under their image.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!
JD

Edit 26 Sept

I realize from the First two answers my question was a bit to fuzzy - the emphasis should have been on the 'authors avatars list' wp plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-avatars/).

In the meantime I have created the following solution: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-author-avatars-list-get-display-excerpt-of-authors-last-post?replies=2#post-1710752

Thanks for you input!
JD

Comment: Yup, it's very simple. Could you please post your DB (database) structure here? I can write the code for you...

Comment: hi tehre - good day dear John - could you plz tell us if you are interested in Wordpress- forums or some others. We do not know this. This would be very helpful - thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-author-avatars-list-get-display-excerpt-of-authors-last-post?replies=2#post-1710752

Answer (score 0):

From get_posts() , you can get all the posts , since each post has a post_author property, you can get all the posts written by each author with a foreach loop, from this you get the latest post per author , and from the latest post , get the post_excerpt content.

Assuming you're using Wordpress...

Comment: Tnx. In the end I used 'query_posts()'.

Comment: hi there john  - glad that it works - do you have a liink to the solution you found out. That would  be great.-

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a hybrid direct SQL and loop approach.

Query for user_ids from the user table who also have a post_author present in the posts table. Loop over those IDs to get their user object and then their latest post. The only thing you lose here is fine grained control over the ordering of users.